# Meteor.methods() converts Float32Array to Object

Tags: mongodb, meteor, buffer, blob, html5-audio

I'm working in Meteor.js with the [recorderJs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) library, and trying to store stereo audio buffers to MongoDB.

On the client, `console.log(buffers)` gives an array of the form

```
[Float32Array, Float32Array]
```

But after passing it to Meteor.methods with `Meteor.call('newSound', buffers)` with the method

```
Meteor.methods({
    newSound: function(buffers) {
        console.log(buffers);
    }
}
```

I get an array like this:

```
[Object, Object]
```

Why is Meteor converting the arrays to objects? Upon retrieval, I need to work with the data as array buffers, and can re-convert them with

```
var buffers = new Array(
    _.toArray(buffers[0]),
    _.toArray(buffers[1])
);
```

but I'm concerned about performance. Should I be converting the buffers to blobs before storing them to the database, then reconverting when I retrieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only EJSON compatible types will be automatically converted from JSON objects to their actual JavaScript type. Read about EJSON here:

http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson

I don't believe `Float32Array` has been made EJSON compatible by the Meteor team. For more information on EJSON and how you can make a type compatible, watch these videos:

- [What is EJSON?](https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/meteor-feed-archive/meteor-what-is-ejson)
- [EJSON in Methods and Subscriptions](https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/meteor-feed-archive/meteor-ejson-in-methods-and-subscriptions)
- [Create a Custom EJSON Type](https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/meteor-feed-archive/meteor-create-a-custom-ejson-type)

There is also [`EJSON.newBinary()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson_new_binary) which may be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble knowing where to begin with this.  The docs say that EJSON supports "`JavaScript Uint8Array` or the result of `EJSON.newBinary`".

Comment: I found a useful article on MDN that explains typed arrays in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays. What I was failing to understand is that these arrays are actually different views of the same binary data.